# How to set array of values to accept property dynamically for input tag in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have following input tag, I need to set the accept value dynamically using array:

```
 <input #myFile type="file" />
```

To set the accept properties dynamically i am using view child:

```
@ViewChild("myFile") myFileRef: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myFileRef.nativeElement.accept = ['.pdf','.doc','.docx','.xlsx', '.xls'];
  }
```

This is not working, is it possible using angular or javascript?

Comment: accept expects a string, not an array of syntax errors

Comment: Why not using binding like `[accept]="value"` if you want to change it?

Answer (score 1):

It works just change what's in your array to strings:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myFileRef.nativeElement.accept = [".doc",".docx",".xlsx", ".xls"];
  }
```

Here you wont find `PDF`s file type while trying to select some files.

**[Working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crzbwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: @bambam [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crzbwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).